# Google Chrome not supporting virtually hosted web app in http

Tags: php, google-chrome, http, web, virtualhost

I have a project virtually hosted in my computer(OS-Ubuntu , LAMP Stack).
The URL is I use to run my web app is http://ecommerce.dev . And It works fine in Firefox, but when I enter same URL in Google Chrome. I get an error saying **This site can’t provide a secure connection  ecommerce.dev sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**
And the URL in the browser automatically changes to https://ecommerce.dev.

So I you guys to solve this problem.

Comment: OR use another browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because now google recognizes .dev as a Tld. Just change the url to http://ecommerce.test or something like that. You can use anything of your choice that doesn't resemble an existing Tld.

Comment: Thank You Very Much